# Use $_POST values by number

Tags: php, forms

i'm not sure how to explain it correctly, but i would like to use `$_POST` values like this `$_POST[0]` and not like this `$_POST['form_field_name']`.

Let's say i have 3 form fields so if i'd like to get data from post like this:

`echo $_POST[0];`
`echo $_POST[1];`
`echo $_POST[2];`

I hope you guys understand what i wanna do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_POSTs variables depends on the `name` attribute of the form element as you can read in this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

On the other hand the attribute `name` of the form elements according to W3C [always must begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata).

But I think you can prepare the $_POST variable before all your code (at the begining of your php script) with:

```
$arrPostVariables = array_values($_POST);
```

And then call them in the way as you want, but I think you will previously must detect the order of the array in order to avoid errors by not having the text of each variable.

Answer (score 10):

Try it like this:

```
 $values = array_values($_POST);
```

No idea why you would do such a thing though.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend ever to refer to your `$_POST` values with indexes, as it is generally a  bad idea.

You can access them by indexes if you do this:

```
$items = array_values($_POST);
$foo = $items[0];
$bar = $items[1]
```

You can also run through your values with a `foreach` loop, like this (which is better, but still bad!)

```
foreach($_POST as $item)
{
    // do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
<input name="0" value="val0" />
<input name="1" value="val1" />
```